# AJAX query to DB onchange, before form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a user setup/create form that includes requesting a users license/certification number as part of the user setup process. However, i need the license information entered to be validated and returned to target DIV **Onchange** before the full form is actually submitted normally. As I understand it, a AJAX POST would be the way to do that but I have never used AJAX. I was looking at an example on W3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp)
but it is using the value set by a single select. In my case I have 3 separate form fields that normally are sanitized and sent to a standalone PHP file thats expecting 3 variables via POST method on SUBMIT like normal.

Can someone show me example of how I could accomplish *the AJAX call* made by the w3schools example when i need to pass/submit 3 variables to receiving PHP processing file, using the POST method when the LAST FORM FIELD is exited (onblur)?

FORM

```
<div>Active license?<input name="sffl" type="checkbox" value="1">Yes | License# 
<input name="dig1" type="text" size="5" maxlength="1" placeholder="5">-
<input name="dig2" type="text" size="8" maxlength="2" placeholder="12">-
<input name="dig3" type="text" size="7" maxlength="3" value="XXX" disabled>-
<input name="dig4" type="text" size="7" maxlength="2" value="XX" disabled>-
<input name="dig5" type="text" size="7" maxlength="2" value="XX" disabled>-
<input name="dig6" type="text" size="10" maxlength="5" placeholder="22131">
</div>
```

TARGET FOR RESPONSE

```
<div id="datatarget">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code I cut and pasted from an ajax call that checks time. It sends more than one variable to the server.

Editing again to point out that this ajax call uses jquery, which some complain about but I find it to be very simple and straightforward for ajax calls.

```
 $("#startdate,#starttime,#enddate,#endtime" ).change(function(){
    $("#date_error").show('');  //clears the error display
    $("#date_error").html('...validating');  //puts a temporary value
    var startdate=$("#startdate").val();  
    var starttime = $("#starttime").val();
    var enddate=$("#enddate").val();
    var endtime=$("#endtime").val();

    startdate = startdate + ' ' + starttime;  //combine date and time
    enddate = enddate + ' ' + endtime;    //combine date and time

    $.post("http://www.mysite.net/contest/validate/",
    {
        startdate:startdate,  //sends to server with post collection
        enddate:enddate,
        id:id
    }, 
    function(data,status) {
      $("#date_error").html(data);

    });  //.post
  }); // keyup
```

Comment: ok, in trying to use what you provided as a base for something i dont know, the code i have as follows works up to the point of assigning the post values to $a, $b, & $c - the POST may be working but i don't known how to get it to the response data back to this page that made the ajax call. Can to tell where this is wrong at or what i need to do different? i need the response to become the innerHTML of #datatarget

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 
$("#dig6").blur(function(){

var $a = $("#dig1").val();  
var $b = $("#dig2").val();
var $c = $("#dig6").val();

$.post("http://www.mywebsite.com/xyz.php",
    {
        var1:$a,  //sends to server with post collection
        var2:$b,
        var3:$c
    },
 function(data,status) {
      $("#datatarget").html(data);

    });  //.post



});

});`

Comment: the line function(data,status) is where you get back the result of the ajax call. Data is what comes back, status is the ...status.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked, as i understand it after a few hours of playing with it this is a combination of jquery/ajax??? in any case this was the end result that was successful:

```
<div>Active license?<input name="sffl" type="checkbox" value="1">Yes | License# 
<input name="dig1" type="text" size="5" maxlength="1" placeholder="5">-
<input name="dig2" type="text" size="8" maxlength="2" placeholder="12">-
<input name="dig3" type="text" size="7" maxlength="3" value="XXX" disabled>-
<input name="dig4" type="text" size="7" maxlength="2" value="XX" disabled>-
<input name="dig5" type="text" size="7" maxlength="2" value="XX" disabled>-
<input name="dig6" type="text" size="10" maxlength="5" placeholder="22131">
</div>
```

m

```
$(document).ready(function()        {

$("#dig6").blur(function(){

$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'test.php',           
            data: {
                var1 : $('#dig1').val(),
                var2 : $('#dig2').val(),
                var3 : $('#dig6').val()
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#datatarget").append(data);
            }     });  });   });
```

test.php contained:

```
echo $_POST["var1"].'<br>';
echo $_POST["var2"].'<br>';
echo $_POST["var3"].'<br>';
```